# Not refreshing in WPF with DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, refresh, wpfdatagrid

Sorry, I have seen this questioned asked a couple of times here already, but none of the answers have solved my problem.

        `public MainWindow()

        {

            _PropertyTenantData = new DataTable();
            _PropertyTenantData.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Property", typeof(string)));
            _PropertyTenantData.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Tenant", typeof(string)));`

```
        DBConnect RentalDatabase = new DBConnect();
        List<string>[] list = new List<string>[2];
        list = RentalDatabase.SelectPropertyTenant();

        var row = _PropertyTenantData.NewRow();
        int numberOfIndividuals = RentalDatabase.CountIndividuals();

        for(int x = 0; x < numberOfIndividuals; x++)
        {
            row = _PropertyTenantData.NewRow();
            _PropertyTenantData.Rows.Add(row);
            row["Property"] = list[0][x];
            row["Tenant"] = list[1][x];

        }

        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

And this is the event that is changing the data.

        `private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

        {

            String tenantFirstName = FirstName.Text;

            String tenantLastName = LastName.Text;

            String street = Street.Text;

            String zipcode = Zipcode.Text;

            String city = City.Text;

            DBConnect RentalDatabase = new DBConnect();

            RentalDatabase.InsertNewTenant(tenantFirstName, tenantLastName);

            RentalDatabase.InsertNewProperty(street, zipcode, city);

            RentalDatabase.InsertNewLease(tenantFirstName, tenantLastName, street);

            FirstName.Clear();

            LastName.Clear();

            Street.Clear();

            Zipcode.Clear();

            City.Clear();

        }`

And it's getting the data from MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried resetting the `DataContext` of your `DataGrid` to your `DataTable` after it has been updated?

**Update**

Your DataTable should be the DataContext of your DataGrid. It looks like you are binding your DataGrid to your DataTable.

```
myGrid.DataContext = myTable;
```

It looks like you are currently updating straight to your DataBase, instead of the DataTable. You need to update your DataTable, and then commit to your DataBase. Once this is done, reset your DataContext your updated Table. It should refresh your DataGrid to the updated data.

Comment: Well, Just started learning WPF so I am not sure how I would reset it. Please explain. Thank you!

Comment: Hmm.. not too sure I follow, due to my lack of understanding of WPF. So would I be updating the DataTable at the event? And how do I update the DataTable before committing it to the DataGrid?

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you mean. I have to send my data from MySql again to the DataTable after I update MySql, or vice-versa.