# C# WPF Sliding Menu: Columns Not Displaying in Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, wpfdatagrid

I checked various links here and the web that dealt with various data grids not showing data but I did not come across one that had a similar scenario as the problem I am having.

[Not refreshing in WPF with DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427979/not-refreshing-in-wpf-with-datagrid?rq=1)

[WPF Does not show data inside datagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886454/wpf-does-not-show-data-inside-datagrid?s=11|0.5950)

[How to get data into datagrid using dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249574/how-to-get-data-into-datagrid-using-dataset?s=27|0.5047)

[DataGridView doesn't show data: DataSet is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18871594/datagridview-doesnt-show-data-dataset-is-empty?s=54|0.3832)

In C# WPF I have created an application that when run, it comes up to a main menu screen with tabs to user pages and different buttons at the top of the page such has: home, exit, update and settings.  The problem I am having is in my settings menu.  When the user clicks on the settings button from the MainWindow a SettingsMainWindow pops up.  In the white section are links that the user clicks on to get to different settings pages and the window to the right slides to the next page depending on what is clicked.

[image: Settings Menu Main Screen]

SettingsMainWindow.xaml

``

```
    <!-- Define supported transitions -->
    <NavigationTransition:NavigationCubeTransition x:Key="CubeTransition" Duration="0:0:0.8"/>
    <NavigationTransition:NavigationSlideTransition x:Key="SlideTransition" Duration="0:0:0.8"/>
    <NavigationTransition:NavigationFlipTransition x:Key="FlipTransition" Duration="0:0:0.8"/>

    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="bvc"/>

</Window.Resources>
<DockPanel Grid.RowSpan="5" Height="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="dockPanelLogin"    VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="auto" Opacity="10" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" OpacityMask="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.MenuTextBrushKey}}" >
    <DockPanel.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </DockPanel.Background>

    <Grid Margin="100">

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <DockPanel Grid.Column="0" LastChildFill="True" Margin="5">

            <!-- Each ComboBoxItem contains the transition in its Tag property
             so that the TransitionContainer can directly databind to the
             selected transition -->
            <ComboBox x:Name="transitionComboBox" SelectedIndex="0" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Margin="0,3,0,0">
                <!--<ComboBoxItem Tag="{StaticResource CubeTransition}">Cube</ComboBoxItem>-->
                <ComboBoxItem Tag="{StaticResource SlideTransition}">Slide</ComboBoxItem>
                <!--<ComboBoxItem Tag="{StaticResource FlipTransition}">Flip</ComboBoxItem>-->
            </ComboBox>

            <ListBox Grid.Column="0"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Views}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                 SelectedIndex="0">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Padding="10"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </DockPanel>

        <Border Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" BorderBrush="#FF7F9DB9" BorderThickness="1">
            <!-- The ContentProperty is not bound directly to the SelectedItem of the ListBox because the
             GoForward property must be updated BEFORE the content changes. The CurrentContent property
             is defined in the ViewModel class and updated everytime the selection of the ListBox changes,
             after setting up the GoForward value. -->
            <NavigationTransition:NavigationPresenter 
            Content="{Binding CurrentContent}"
            Transition="{Binding ElementName=transitionComboBox, Path=SelectedItem.Tag}"
            GoForward="{Binding DataContext.GoForward, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type NavigationTransition:NavigationSlideTransition}}}"/>
        </Border>
        <!--Region Editor-->
        <Grid Grid.RowSpan="100" Grid.ColumnSpan="100"
          Background="#88000000" Visibility="{Binding IsShowingPage3View, Converter={StaticResource bvc}, FallbackValue=Collapsed}">
            <View:Page3View Margin="0, 200, 0, 0"
                                           x:Name="page3View" DataContext="{Binding}" Width="800" Height="700"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

My issue is showing data from my Access DB in the data grid on the page below.  This grid should be auto populated with the regions table information upon load, where the user can add additional regional information. There should be four columns showing in the below when run. I have implemented this same feature elsewhere in my application that is not in a menu and it works just fine.  When in debug it shows that it is reading the table properly but it’s just not showing nor giving any errors.  My question is how to get this to show the required data while being within a menu page.

[image: Runtime View of Region Update Page]

Page3View.xaml

```
<Border BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HotTrackBrushKey}}" 
        BorderThickness="1" 
        Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GradientActiveCaptionBrushKey}}"
        Padding="20">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1">
            <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="100" Height="6" Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.MenuHighlightBrushKey}}" />
            <TextBlock FontSize="24" Foreground="#444444" FontWeight="Bold" Text="REGION-DISTRICT NAME EDITOR" />
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Height="10"/>

        <DataGrid x:Name="dg" Grid.Row="2" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                      VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                      CanUserAddRows="True"
                      CanUserDeleteRows="True"
                      CanUserResizeRows="False"
                      CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                      CanUserResizeColumns="True"
                      CanUserSortColumns="False"
                        VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"

                      AutoGenerateColumns="True">

        </DataGrid>

        <!--<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding TaskbarProgressValue, Converter={StaticResource ProgressBarStartButtonEnabledConverter}}">
            <Button Style="{StaticResource PanelCloseButtonStyle}" Margin="0" Click="btnClose_Click" />
        </StackPanel>-->

        <StackPanel Margin="0, 10, 0, 0" Grid.Row="4" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <Button Height="Auto" Click="btnSubmit_Click" Content="OK" Command="{Binding ToggleRegionEditorsCommand}" CommandParameter="{StaticResource False}" Width="90"/>
            <StackPanel Width="10" />
            <Button Height="Auto" Click="btnClose_Click" Content="Cancel" Command="{Binding ToggleRegionEditorsCommand}" CommandParameter="{StaticResource False}" Width="90" />
        </StackPanel>

        <!--Added for page 3 region editor-->
        <!--<Grid Grid.RowSpan="100" Grid.ColumnSpan="100"
          Background="#88000000" Visibility="{Binding IsShowingPage3View, Converter={StaticResource bvc}, FallbackValue=Collapsed}">
            <View:Page3View Margin="0, 200, 0, 0"
                                           x:Name="page3View" DataContext="{Binding}" Width="800" Height="700"/>
        </Grid>-->

    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Page3View.xaml.cs

```
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Page3View.xaml Region Distric Editor
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Page3View : UserControl
{
    public Page3View()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private IDbDriver Database { get; set; }
    private DataHelper DataHelper { get; set; }

    public void Init(DataHelper dataHelper)
    {
        if (dg.ItemsSource != null)
        {
            dg.ItemsSource = null;
        }

        Database = dataHelper.Database;
        DataHelper = dataHelper;

        Query selectQuery = Database.CreateQuery("SELECT DRS, RegCode, DISTRICT, DistCode FROM [codedistrict1] ORDER BY DRS, DISTRICT");
        DataTable dt = Database.Select(selectQuery);
        dg.ItemsSource = (dt).DefaultView;
    }

    private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dg.ItemsSource != null)
        {
            DataView dv = dg.ItemsSource as DataView;
            if (dv != null && dv.Table != null)
            {
                DataTable dt = dv.Table;
                if (dt != null && Database != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string querySyntax = "DELETE * FROM [codedistrict1]";
                        if (Database.ToString().ToLower().Contains("sql"))
                        {
                            querySyntax = "DELETE FROM [codedistrict1]";
                        }

                        Query deleteQuery = Database.CreateQuery(querySyntax);
                        Database.ExecuteNonQuery(deleteQuery);

                        DataRow[] rows = dt.Select(String.Empty, String.Empty, DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);

                        foreach (DataRow row in rows)
                        {
                            Query insertQuery = Database.CreateQuery("INSERT INTO [codedistrict1] (DRS, RegCode, DISTRICT, DistCode) VALUES (" +
                                "@DRS, @RegCode, @DISTRICT, @DistCode)");
                            insertQuery.Parameters.Add(new QueryParameter("@DRS", DbType.String, row[0].ToString()));
                            insertQuery.Parameters.Add(new QueryParameter("@RegCode", DbType.String, row[1].ToString()));
                            insertQuery.Parameters.Add(new QueryParameter("@DISTRICT", DbType.String, row[2].ToString()));
                            insertQuery.Parameters.Add(new QueryParameter("@DistCode", DbType.String, row[3].ToString()));
                            Database.ExecuteNonQuery(insertQuery);
                        }

                        MessageBox.Show("Changes were committed to the database successfully.", "Success", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Changes were not committed to the database successfully. Error: " + ex.Message, "Failure", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

DataHelper.cs

```
public class DataHelper : DataHelperBase
{
    #region Members
    private bool _isShowingPage3View = false;
    #endregion

    #region Properties

    // Shows the region districts update page for the settings page
    public bool IsShowingPage3View
    {
        get
        {
            return this._isShowingPage3View;
        }
        set
        {
            if (!IsShowingPage3View == value)
            {
                this._isShowingPage3View = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("IsShowingPage3View");
            }
        }
    }

  // This is for the region district editor on the settings page
    public ICommand TogglePage3ViewCommand { get { return new    RelayCommand<bool>   TogglePage3ViewCommandExecute); } }
    private void TogglePage3ViewCommandExecute(bool show)
    {
        IsShowingPage3View = show;
    }




   private void btnSettings_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            {
                Regions.View.Page3View.Int(this.DataHelper);
            }
        }
```

With the above code I am now getting an error that it does not contain a definition for Int although it is defined on Page3View. It should be tied to this block of code.

```
public void Init(DataHelper dataHelper)
    {
        if (dg.ItemsSource != null)
        {
            dg.ItemsSource = null;
        }

        Database = dataHelper.Database;
        DataHelper = dataHelper;

        Query selectQuery = Database.CreateQuery("SELECT DRS, RegCode, DISTRICT, DistCode FROM [codedistrict1] ORDER BY DRS, DISTRICT");
        DataTable dt = Database.Select(selectQuery);
        dg.ItemsSource = (dt).DefaultView;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show where and how the `Init(DataHelper dataHelper)` method is called from?

Comment: @Rachel private IDbDriver Database { get; set; }
        private DataHelper DataHelper { get; set; }
    public void Init(DataHelper dataHelper)
        {
            if (dg.ItemsSource != null)
            {
                dg.ItemsSource = null;
            }

            Database = dataHelper.Database;
            DataHelper = dataHelper;

            Query selectQuery = Database.CreateQuery("SELECT DRS, RegCode, DISTRICT, DistCode FROM [codedistrict1] ORDER BY DRS, DISTRICT");
            DataTable dt = Database.Select(selectQuery);
            dg.ItemsSource = (dt).DefaultView;
        }

Comment: I meant where is that method called from? Can you [edit] your question to include the code?

Comment: @Rachel I have edited the question to include the code.

Comment: Its really hard to tell from your code, but my best guess would be that either `Regions.View.Page3View` is not the same as the instance created in the XAML that is being displayed, or if this is running on a background thread then maybe the `ItemsSource` gets set at a later dispatcher priority, causing it to need a refresh. The 2nd is easy to test - minimize the app and restore it, and if this is the case you should now see your data. I suspect it's the first issue though.